# Insert value does not match column list:1136

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to insert a record to a table with 2 column but I get this error.
My error starts in part of the execute. Anyone that can help me out with this ?
I am using PDO.

My code:

```
global $conn_kl;
$sql = $conn_kl->prepare("INSERT INTO order_producten VALUES (?,?)");
$sql->execute(array($product_id, $bewerking_id));
```

Comment: specify column name in your query like this : INSERT INTO order_producten`(column_name1, column_name2)` VALUES (?,?)

Comment: Can you show the structure of `order_producten`

Comment: I found a stupid fault in my code earlier, Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order_producten will have more or less than two columns and you are setting only two values.

Please specify columns after table name. for example,

```
INSERT INTO order_producten(id, name) VALUES(?, ?)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My table has only 2 columns and I want to set 2 values. I was forgotten to say I use PDO and earlier created functions with same code were working for me. So this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @jol123: Then There must be some other query that is failing and not this one. Because error message is clear that insert value does not match column list.

Comment: Only when I execute this function it will give me that error. Maybe There's something wrong in my code before I try to execute ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
INSERT INTO order_producten VALUES (?,?)
```

here columns are not defined in this query, in this case it is expected that you have to pass the values for all columns in the table. But you want to insert the values for only   2 columns, so please please specify that columns names like:

```
INSERT INTO order_producten(column_name1, column_name2) VALUES (?,?)
```

Answer (score -1):

For example, code something like this were working for me:

```
global $conn_kl;
    $sql = $conn_kl->prepare("INSERT INTO `order_bewerkingen` VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?)");
    $sql->execute(array($order_id, $method, $position));
```

Comment: this is no- where answer to a question, it need to be added into the question itself.please delete it